# Type list does not want to compile

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming

I am trying to implement some kind of type list. I am wondering why the following code doesn't compile.
In my opinion it should at least compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Non_t {};

template<typename THead, typename TTail = Non_t>
struct Type_list
{
    using Head = THead;
    using Tail = TTail;
};

struct Conv1 {};
struct Conv2 {};
struct Conv3 {};

using Types = 
    Type_list<Conv1
>;

template<typename TTypeList, typename TWanted>
void dispatch()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TTypeList, Non_t>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "Not found :( " << std::endl;
        
        return; 
    }
    
    using Head = typename TTypeList::Head;
    using Tail = typename TTypeList::Tail;
    using Wanted = TWanted;

    if constexpr (!std::is_same<Head, Wanted>::value)
    {
        dispatch<Tail, Wanted>();
    }
    else 
    {
       std::cout << "It works" << std::endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    dispatch<Types, Conv3>();

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine only when type list contains the type I need.

I tried either gcc 9.3 and clang 10.

Both compilers shows similar error message which is: 'error: no type named ‘Head’ in ‘struct Non_t’'

I tried to compile this code in https://godbolt.org/ by using clang 10, and I can see following hints from clang:

> note: in instantiation of function template specialization `dispatch<Type_list<Conv1, Non_t>, Conv3>`requested herex86-64 clang 10.0.0 #1
>
> note: in instantiation of function template specialization `dispatch<Type_list<Conv1, Non_t>, Conv3>` requested herex86-64 clang 10.0.0 #1

Edit:
It compiles only if I wrap the part of function after first 'if statement' into another else block. Why is that?

Comment: The fact that your `using Head = ...` etc comes after your `if constexpr` does not make any difference here. It must still be valid. You can wrap the rest of `dispatch` in an `else`.

Comment: Because the code needs to make sense at compile-time. Just because we won't reach that section of code during runtime doesn't mean that we are allowed to write invalid code without compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because, as the error says, `Non_t` doesn't have a type named `Head`. The fact that your `using Head = ...` statement comes after your return does not make any difference.

Let's look at a counter example.

```
int main() {
    int i = 2;
    return i;

    i.thisIsNotValid();
}
```

Here we will get a compilation error. It doesn't matter that we'll never reach that part of the code during runtime. That's not a consideration the compiler does. It simply makes sure that all written code is valid and generates machine code for it.

On the other hand, using a `if constexpr` and `else` block we tell the compiler to evaluate something at compile-time and only use one of the branches. The other one is completely discarded.

```
template<typename TTypeList, typename TWanted>
void dispatch()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TTypeList, Non_t>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "Not found :( " << std::endl;

        return; 
    } else {

        using Head = typename TTypeList::Head;
        using Tail = typename TTypeList::Tail;
        using Wanted = TWanted;

        if constexpr (!std::is_same<Head, Wanted>::value)
        {
            dispatch<Tail, Wanted>();
        }
        else 
        {
           std::cout << "It works" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the lower part of the function will get completely discarded **at compile-time** if the condition is true.